# Making Custom Linked List work with PODs

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, linked-list

This has been bothering me for like forever, since I've written my LinkedList implementation a few months back.

This is the problem: I work in an  environment where the standard library (of any kind) is not available, so I've to create everything myself.

Since it's a rather specialised environment (ie. OSDev) the use cases for my linked list are small. However, seeing as I'm a lazy person, I'd like to use the same library for userspace programs... This would involve expanding the operable scope of the list.

As for the code, I've pasted it at the end (SO really should either allow pastebin and such, or create an SO-branded pastebin-esque thing, or have some kind of embeddable code thing that opens an overlay window when you click it).

This is the problem: I usually create the LinkedList as such:

```
LinkedList<PCIDevice>* list = new LinkedList<PCIDevice>();
```

then, list->Front() for instance would return PCIDevice*, or a pointer to PCIDevice. This usually works for me because most of my objects are manually allocated with new/delete.

Unfortunately, if I try anything like

```
LinkedList<int>* list = new LinkedList<int>();
list->InsertFront(10);
```

It expects a int* for the InsertFront call. This has stumped me for a long time, how and what should I do?

I think that I would have to do something along the lines of

```
LinkedList<PCIDevice*>* list = new LinkedList<PCIDevice*>();
```

To get a list of pointers to PCIDevice... but I'm still a little confused about non pointer complex classes and return values and method call parameters... so if someone could explain that a bit as well, it would be much appreciated.

CODE:

```
template <class data>
class LinkedList
{
    private:
        template <typename obj>
        class SingleNode
        {
            public:
                SingleNode(obj* o = 0, SingleNode<obj>* n = 0)
                {
                    this->object = (obj*)o;
                    this->next = n;
                    this->magic = 0xBEEFBEEFBEEFBEEF;
                }

                SingleNode<obj>* next;
                obj* object;
                uint64_t magic;
        };

        uint64_t length;
        uint64_t size;
        SingleNode<data>* head;
        SingleNode<data>* tail;


        SingleNode<data>* Traverse(uint64_t i) const
        {
            SingleNode<data>* h = this->head;
            // if(i >= this->length)
            //  HALT("List index out of bounds.");

            if(this->length == 1 || i == 0)
            {
                return this->head;
            }
            else if(this->length == 2 && i == 1)
            {
                return this->tail;
            }
            for(uint64_t l = 0; l < i; l++)
            {
                h = h->next;
            }
            return h;
        }





    public:
        // this needs to be already allocated; give a head pointer.
        LinkedList()
        {
            this->head = 0;
            this->tail = 0;
            this->length = 0;
            this->size = sizeof(data);
        }
        ~LinkedList()
        {
            // delete all nodes
            for(uint64_t i = 0, m = this->length; i < m; i++)
            {
                SingleNode<data>* s = this->head;
                this->head = this->head->next;

                delete s;
            }
        }


        uint64_t Size(){ return this->length; }
        bool IsEmpty(){ return this->length == 0; }
        data* Get(uint64_t i) const
        {
            if(i >= this->length)
            {
                asm volatile("xchg %bx, %bx");
            }

            if(this->length == 1 || i == 0)
            {
                return this->head->object;
            }
            else if(i == this->length - 1)
            {
                return this->tail->object;
            }

            return this->Traverse(i)->object;
        }






        void InsertFront(data* obj)
        {
            SingleNode<data>* f = new SingleNode<data>(obj, this->head);


            if(this->IsEmpty())
            {
                this->head = f;
                this->tail = f;
            }
            else
            {
                this->head = f;
            }

            this->length++;
        }

        void InsertBack(data* obj)
        {
            SingleNode<data>* f = new SingleNode<data>(obj, 0);

            if(this->IsEmpty())
            {
                this->head = f;
            }
            else
            {
                this->tail->next = f;
            }

            this->tail = f;
            this->length++;
        }

        void AddAll(LinkedList<data>* l)
        {
            for(uint64_t i = 0; i < l->Size(); i++)
            {
                this->InsertBack(l->Get(i));
            }
        }

        data* RemoveFront()
        {
            // if(this->head == 0)
            //  HALT("Removing from empty list");

            data* obj = this->head->object;
            SingleNode<data>* old_head = this->head;

            if(this->length == 1)
            {
                this->head = 0;
                this->tail = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this->head = this->head->next;
            }

            delete old_head;
            this->length--;
            return obj;
        }

        data* RemoveBack()
        {
            // if(this->tail == 0)
            //  HALT("Removing from empty list!");

            SingleNode<data>* old_tail = this->tail;
            data* obj = this->tail->object;


            if(this->length == 1)
            {
                this->head = 0;
                this->tail = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                SingleNode<data>* kr = this->head;
                while(kr->next != this->tail)
                    kr = kr->next;

                kr->next = 0;
                this->tail = kr;
            }

            delete old_tail;
            this->length--;
            return obj;
        }

        data* Back()
        {
            return this->tail->object;
        }

        data* Front()
        {
            return this->head->object;
        }

        void Clear()
        {
            for(uint64_t m = 0, g = this->length; m < g; m++)
            {
                this->RemoveFront();
            }
        }

        int64_t IndexOf(data* p)
        {
            for(int64_t d = 0; (uint64_t)d < this->length; d++)
            {
                if(p == this->Get((uint64_t)d))
                    return d;
            }

            return -1;
        }

        data* RemoveAt(uint64_t i)
        {
            // if(i >= this->length)
            //  HALT("List index out of bounds");

            if(i == 0)
                return this->RemoveFront();

            if(i == this->length - 1)
                return this->RemoveBack();


            data* ret = this->Get(i);
            SingleNode<data>* k = this->Traverse(i);
            SingleNode<data>* p = this->Traverse(i - 1);

            p->next = k->next;
            delete k;
            this->length--;

            return ret;
        }

        void InsertAt(uint64_t i, data* d)
        {
            if(i >= this->length)
                this->InsertBack(d);

            else if(i == 0)
                this->InsertFront(d);

            else
            {
                SingleNode<data>* p = this->Traverse(i - 1);
                SingleNode<data>* t = this->Traverse(i);
                SingleNode<data>* n = this->Traverse(i + 1);
                p->next = new SingleNode<data>(d, t);
                t->next = n;
                this->length++;
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're worried about is whether or not the complex data type will behave just like an `int` when you go to store it. The answer is that so long as it has a "Copy Constructor" (a constructor that accepts a type `ClassName&` and duplicates all the data in it) then it will act exactly as you expect it to.

Comment: So what changes do I have to make? Should I change all the T* to simply T? or T&?

Comment: @zhiayang yes, make them all T and just require that T has a Copy Constructor.

Comment: Yup, managed to get that working. Although shouldn't things like Front() and Back() etc. return references?

Comment: @zhiayang Yup, just like they do in the STL